# CloudTable vs TableServiceContext in Azure Storage Client Library 2.0

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I earlier was using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient 1.7 and all DAL methods using [TableServiceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.dataservices.tableservicecontext.aspx) to add, delete, update, get, find and submit changes.
Now i moved to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 2.0 and removed all the references to older library.
Can I still use [TableServiceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.dataservices.tableservicecontext.aspx) methods or is it recommended to change all the add, delete, get and submit code to use [CloudTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it were me, I wouldn't change all the code unless there was a legit need to do so.  How much code would need changed also plays a factor in that decision.

Have you reviewed these two resources for additional info on the new features in the latest storage client library:

- Windows Azure Storage Client Library 2.0 Table Deep Dive - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/06/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive.aspx
- Windows Azure Storage Client Library 2.0 Breaking Changes & Migration Guide - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-breaking-changes-amp-migration-guide.aspx